# Class member attributes error

Tags: c++

I have two classes and want to have a reference from class Kunde to class Konto and backward, but my compiler shows many errors. I don't know what the problem is. Please help me.

Class Konto:

```
#pragma once
#include "Kunde.h"

class Konto {
private:
    Kunde* kunde;
protected:
    int kontonummer;
    double stand;
public:
    int getKontonummer();
    Kunde* getKunde();
    double getKontostand();
    bool einzahlen(double betrag);
    virtual bool auszahlen(double betrag);
};
```

Class Kunde:

```
#pragma once
#include "Konto.h"
#include <string>

class Kunde {
private:
    string vorname;
    string nachname;
    Konto* konto;
public:
    Kunde(string vorname, string nachname);
    void setKonto(Konto* konto);
    Konto* getKonto();
};
```

I get following compiler errrors:

> konto.h(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
>   konto.h(6): error C4430: missing typespecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support "default-int"
>   konto.h(6): error C4430: missing typespecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support "default-int"

and some more.

Comment: Not to do with your question, but as someone that has worked fairly extensively in Europe, I've found that using tools that are translated into your local language will only limit you. You will not be able to search for common error messages, and people like me may not be able to explain them. Use English language tools, whatever your local resellers may try to foist on you. And writing the code in English is a good idea too.

Comment: You are right, I did not give much attention to this point, because I solved most problems without sarching for a solution. But it was still posted when I noticed it. Thanks for your advice, I will change the translation to english. Concerning the code, I want to giv ea colleaque a simple example for learning oop, and that is in this case quite easier when I am coding it in german ;)

Comment: BTW please note (before a rain of comments descends) I have nothing against the German language or Germans - I spent two happy years at RAF Jever in north Germany as  a child.

Comment: I did not understand it as an "attack" against german language. I totally support your comment - this is a international website, so english is way of communication!

Comment: I didn't expect complaint from you, but possibly from some politically correct nutcases here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular inclusion problem. You see the `#pragma once` statement in the first line of the header file? This prevents an inclusion of the header if it has already been included. Since your header files include each other, at the declaration of either `Kunde` or `Konto` the other one has not yet been defined.

You can circumvent the problem if you make a simple forward declaration of either class in the other header file. Specifically:

(Konto.h)

```
#pragma once

// Do NOT include Kunde.h

class Kunde;

class Konto {
    // your further class definition as normal.
```

The only thing is that you now should include `Kunde.h` in the `Konto.cpp`, or else this would lead to a linker error.

EDIT: see comments :) thanks

Comment: "circumnavigte" - I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Otherwise, nice explanation. +1. "Circumvent."

Answer (score 4):

The header files can't include each other. Instead of the #includes, try a forward declaration in one or both, like this:

```
class Kunde;
```

Answer (score 1):

Including one file in another that includes the first file, that includes the second file that  includes the first file...

surely will confuse `#pragma once`

Answer (score 1):

Konto is including Kunde.h and Kunde is including Konto.h. Do a forward declaration in both cases

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic circular dependency. You can handle it a couple ways. The first is to use forward declarations for the other class you are trying to reference. You'll need to remove the include for the other class too.

class Konto;

class Kunde
{
    Konto* konto;
...
};

The other way is to abstract out an interface that gives you what you want. I can go into further detail on that approach if you like.